# keywords like var re-initialize the global variables in functions?

Tags: javascript

if i write something like this:

```
var a = 1;
function lol(){
console.log(a);
}
lol();
```

it outputs 1 as intended, as i initialized a=1 in global scope. So i thought in function it initialized its value as well.
But when i write something like this:

```
var a = 1;
function lol(){
var a = a + a;
console.log(a);
}
lol();
```

it outputs NaN, which confuses me, cuz i thought the variable has already been initialized in global scope.

Here's my thoughts, don't know if it's correct or not, so i'm asking: i think the keywords like *var/let/const*, each time it's mentioned, it kind of re-initialize the variable or what? and since the second *var* is in block scope, so when mentioned with *var*, the variable **a** goes initialized again and thus becomes undefined, outputs NaN.

am i correct? plz help.

Comment: First of course, don't use `var` because it's an older keyword for declaring variables with _functions cope_ (or global, if outside a function), which is basically nothing like what any other language does. Instead, use `let` for variables you want to be able to assign new values to later on, and `const` for variables that should be assigned at declare time and then never reassigned. Both of those use _block scope_. But second: by using `var a` inside a function, you create a _new_ variable that happens to have the same name as some higher-scope var, and does not exist outside the function.

Comment: You could check your hypothesis by outputting `a` *after* calling `lol`.

Comment: [Function/variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i've tried using _let_ as well, it outputs the same. Still much thanks for ur advice, i will try to abandon using _var_.

Comment: Oh no, absolutely: it'll still output the same because `var a = a + a` inside that function means you're declaring a new variable `a` which immediately shadows the global `a`, and then your assignment uses that new, not let defined, `a`. The _declaration_ immediately hides the higher-scoped variable by the same name, JS doesn't wait until after the assignment. So your code is telling the JS engine to evaluate `undefined + undefined`, which is not a number.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks! sorry was just a beginner to js, i'm dumb.

Comment: Ignorance is not the same as being dumb, never call yourself dumb for not knowing what you _can't_ know yet.

Comment: @Starx Actually if you use `let a = a+a`, it should no longer output `NaN`, it should throw a proper exception explaining why this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize the variable then just use the same variable

```js
var a = 1;
function lol(){
a = a + a;
console.log(a);
}
lol();
```

at statement `var a = a + a;`  you are defining altogether different variable which was not initialize before arithmetic operation so it is resulting `NaN` compiler declared another variable with same name `a`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's happening because of hoisting. Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#var_hoisting

As per MDN,

> JavaScript Hoisting refers to the process whereby the interpreter appears to move the declaration of functions, variables or classes to the top of their scope, prior to execution of the code.